# I m trying to build auto complete for HTML tags in <textarea> in React, but so far no success. Could someone assist me?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, textarea

So the user enters the tag (like `<body>`) and the funcation should end it with (`</div>`).
Pls see my code below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Text = () => {
    const [currentText, setCurrentText] = useState("");

    const addClosingTag = (event) => {
        // const txtBefore = event.target.value.slice(0, event.target.selectionStart);
        const txtBef = currentText.slice(0,currentText.selectionStart);
        const txtAft = currentText.slice(currentText.selectionEnd, currentText.length);
        const lastString = txtBef.replace(/\s+/g, " ").split(" ")[txtBef.replace(/\s+/g, " ").split(" ").length - 1];

        if (event.key == ">") {
            if(lastString.includes("<")){
                var addClose = lastString.replace(/[< >]/g, "");
                setCurrentText(`${txtBef}</${addClose}>${txtAft}`);
            }
        }
        
    } 

    return (
        <div>
            <textarea 
                value={currentText}
                onChange={(event) => setCurrentText(event.target.value)}
                onKeyDown={(event) => addClosingTag(event)}
            />
        </div>
    )
};

export default Text;
```

It would be great if the function will not trigger if it **NOT** `html` tag like: `<laptop>`

I am trying to close the html tag after they have been decalred, so far the funcation doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to overcome this issue.

```
const Text = () => {
    const [currentText, setCurrentText] = useState();

    const allHTMLTags = [
        "a",
        "abbr",
        "address",
        "area",
        "article",
        "aside",
        "audio",
        "b",
        "base",
        "bdi",
        "bdo",
        "blockquote",
        "body",
        "br",
        "button",
        "canvas",
        "caption",
        "cite",
        "code",
        "col",
        "colgroup",
        "data",
        "datalist",
        "dd",
        "del",
        "details",
        "dfn",
        "dialog",
        "div",
        "dl",
        "dt",
        "em",
        "embed",
        "fieldset",
        "figcaption",
        "figure",
        "footer",
        "form",
        "h1",
        "h2",
        "h3",
        "h4",
        "h5",
        "h6",
        "head",
        "header",
        "hgroup",
        "hr",
        "html",
        "i",
        "iframe",
        "img",
        "input",
        "ins",
        "kbd",
        "label",
        "legend",
        "li",
        "link",
        "main",
        "map",
        "mark",
        "math",
        "menu",
        "menuitem",
        "meta",
        "meter",
        "nav",
        "noscript",
        "object",
        "ol",
        "optgroup",
        "option",
        "output",
        "p",
        "param",
        "picture",
        "pre",
        "progress",
        "q",
        "rb",
        "rp",
        "rt",
        "rtc",
        "ruby",
        "s",
        "samp",
        "script",
        "section",
        "select",
        "slot",
        "small",
        "source",
        "span",
        "strong",
        "style",
        "sub",
        "summary",
        "sup",
        "svg",
        "table",
        "tbody",
        "td",
        "template",
        "textarea",
        "tfoot",
        "th",
        "thead",
        "time",
        "title",
        "tr",
        "track",
        "u",
        "ul",
        "var",
        "video",
        "wbr"
    ]
    
    const addClosingTag =(elem, evt) => {
        var txtBef = elem.value.slice(0, elem.selectionEnd);
        var txtAft = elem.value.slice(elem.selectionEnd, elem.value.lenth);
        var lastString = txtBef
            .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
            .split(" ");
        lastString = lastString[lastString.length - 1];
        
        if(evt.key == ">" && allHTMLTags.includes(lastString.slice(1, lastString.length - 1))) {
            if(lastString.includes("<")){
                var addClose = lastString.replace(/[< >]/g, ""); 
                elem.value = `${txtBef}  </${addClose}> ${txtAft}`;
                elem.selectionEnd = txtBef.length +1; 
            }
        }
    }

    const showText = () => {
        alert(currentText);
        setCurrentText("");
    }

    return (
        <div style = {{marging: '100px'}}>
            <textarea 
                style = {{width: "400px", height: "150px"}}
                value = {currentText}
                onChange = {(event) => setCurrentText(event.target.value)}
                onKeyUp = {(event) => addClosingTag(event.target, event)}
            />
            <button onClick={showText}> show here </button>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Text;
```

Bonus, I added all HTML tags so if the user adds not HTML tag it will not add closing tag